# Fetching Specific Orders

Tags: php, mysql

This is the query I have written to fetch the records from 3 different tables and display them in one simple table.

```
$order_id=$_REQUEST['a'];
$query="select DISTINCT product.productId,orders.id,retailerName, total, status, delivery,shopName,ownerName,address,email,contact,notes,order_item.quantity,order_item.date,productName,price,product.detail,product.price,product.expiry from orders,checkout,order_item,product where product.productId=order_item.productId and orders.id ='".$order_id."' and orders.id=order_item.orderId and orders.id=checkout.orderId";
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
```

The below code is written for display of record and detail.

```
<?PHP
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
?>   
<tr>
    <?php
    $subtotal=0;
    $subtotal = $row['quantity'] * $row['price'];
    $total += $subtotal;
    ?>
    <td><?php echo $row['productName'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['quantity'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['price'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $subtotal;?></td>
</tr>
<?PHP
}
?>
```

It displays all of the orders from database whereas I want the orders to be displayed for specific company.

Comment: this has to do with your database structure and how you linked all entities in your app. Do you have an ERD?

Comment: Side note: please read about SQL injection, prepared statements and XSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have button for show only one result you should link it with some id. 
For example:

```
<a href="del.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" id="button1" name="button1">Delete</a>
```

Make SQL query show only one result: use **WHERE** clause.

```
 if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
    $q = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id = '$id'";
    }
$db->query($q);
```